# How to start SpiderOak from a command line in a headless mode and then close cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, parameters

I'm trying to start SpiderOak in a headless mode from a command line on Windows 7. After the application starts I would like to be able to close the command line without interrupting the process.

According to the manual, the parameter for no-GUI mode is `--headless` (https://spideroak.com/faq/questions/67/how_can_i_use_spideroak_from_the_commandline/)

```
c:\"Program Files"\SpiderOak\SpiderOak.exe --headless
```

I've tried:

```
start "" "c:\Program Files\SpiderOak\SpiderOak.exe" --headless
```

But when I close the command line window the programm closes.

When I don't add the `--headless` parameter, everything works fine

```
start "" "c:\Program Files\SpiderOak\SpiderOak.exe"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot help you if you persist to start SpiderOak from the commandline.

However if your goal is just to start SpiderOak in no-GUI mode and forget about it (I needed that), this is what you have to do:

1. Create a shortcut to the SpiderOak app.
2. Open its properties and add the paramater in the shortcut section:
   "C:\Program Files\SpiderOak\SpiderOak.exe" --headless
3. Save and close
4. Now you can also move this shortcut to the autorun if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to configure a windows service that will run SpiderOak. Try with and without `--headless`. I've read that systray icons may disappear when run as a service, so leaving this parameter out may prevent this (and still give you the no-window feature).